# Angular 2 typing issue when using subject

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I've have a problem when using subjects in Angular 2. I get the following error when running the app:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'UserDevice[]'.)`

- I have a component with a list of userDevices.
- And a service which provides the userDevices.

// Service

```
export class UserDeviceLocalService {

    udSubject = new ReplaySubject();
    tmpUserDevices: UserDevice[] = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    createUserDevices(userDevice){
    this.tmpUserDevices.push(userDevice);

    // localStorage.setItem('userdevices', JSON.stringify(this.tmpUserDevices));
    this.udSubject.next(this.tmpUserDevices);
    }
 }
```

// component

```
export class UserDeviceMenuComponent implements OnInit {

userDevices: UserDevice[];

constructor(private userDeviceLocalService: UserDeviceLocalService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.userDeviceLocalService.udSubject.subscribe(userDevices => this.userDevices = userDevices);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createUserDevices(userDevice){
    this.tmpUserDevices.push(userDevice);
    this.udSubject.next(this.tmpUserDevices);
    }
```

Also:

```
export class UserDeviceLocalService {
    udSubject = new ReplaySubject<UserDevice[]>();
    ...
}
```

and make sure you unsubscribe the observable when the component destroyed to avoid memory leak.

```
export class UserDeviceMenuComponent implements OnInit {

userDevices: UserDevice[];
supscription: Subscription;

constructor(private userDeviceLocalService: UserDeviceLocalService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.userDeviceLocalService.udSubject.subscribe(userDevices => this.userDevices = userDevices);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscription.unsubscribe();   
}
```

Or use `async` pipe which handles the unsubscription for you.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this line need change

```
this.udSubject.next(userDevice);
```

to

```
this.udSubject.next(tmpUserDevices);
```

because `userDevice` is a object, not array of object

Comment: Yes you're right. I have done this for testing only. I have edited my code, still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You should specify type when declaring/instantiating your `Subject` field:

```
udSubject = new ReplaySubject<UserDevice[]>();
```

In your example, what you probably need is `new ReplaySubject<UserDevice[]>(1);` so only the last value is replayed.

In such case you could also use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `ReplaySubject` and eliminate `tmpUserDevices`:

```
export class UserDeviceLocalService {

    udSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserDevice[]>([]);

    createUserDevices(userDevice: UserDevice) {
        let devices = this.udSubject.value;

        // maybe clone array first?
        devices = devices.slice();

        devices.push(userDevice);

        // localStorage.setItem('userdevices', JSON.stringify(devices));
        this.udSubject.next(devices);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to un-subscribe subscription(s) on `ngOnDestroy()`.

This article explains some aspects of TypeScript type system:

http://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-does-it-really-work-when-are-two-types-compatible-its-actually-quite-different-than-other-type-systems/